# Creating .deb with javahelper

Tags: package-management, dpkg, packaging

I have already lost the full day trying to figure out what I'm doing bad. I can't package my Java application into .deb package.

The steps I'm doing are:
1) Copy the src files into folder with name: something-1.2
2) Run jh_makepkg in the directory where something-1.2 is situated
3) In something-1.2/debian/:

- edit rules file (only adding CLASSPATH)
- edit control file adding Version and Homepage
- edit something.install adding some more files to be copied
- edit something.manifest editing Main-Class

4) I run dpkg-buildpackage -d inside the something-1.2 folder and I got an error:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -d
dpkg-buildpackage: set CFLAGS to default value: -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: set CPPFLAGS to default value:
dpkg-buildpackage: set LDFLAGS to default value: -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions
dpkg-buildpackage: set FFLAGS to default value: -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: set CXXFLAGS to default value: -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: source package something
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 1.2-1
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by <some1@example.com>
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture i386
   debian/rules clean
dh --with javahelper clean
   dh_testdir
   dh_auto_clean
   dh_clean
   jh_clean
dpkg-source -b something-1.2
dpkg-source: warning: unknown information field 'Version' in input data in general     section of control info file
dpkg-source: info: using source format `1.0'
dpkg-source: info: building something in something_1.2-1.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: building something in something_1.2-1.dsc
debian/rules build
dh --with javahelper build
   dh_testdir
   dh_auto_configure
   dh_auto_build
   jh_build
find src -name *.java -and -type f -print0 | xargs -0 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/javac -cp /home/lib/jdom.jar:/home/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar:debian/_jh_build.something -d debian/_jh_build.something
fastjar -c -f /home/user/FP/something-1.2/something.jar -m ../_jh_manifest.something probe
dh_auto_test
debian/rules binary
dh --with javahelper binary
    dh_testroot
    dh_prep
    dh_installdirs
    dh_auto_install
    dh_install
    dh_installdocs
    dh_installchangelogs
    dh_installexamples
    dh_installman
    dh_installcatalogs
    dh_installcron
    dh_installdebconf
    dh_installcatalogs
    dh_installemacsen
    dh_installifupdown
    dh_installinfo
    dh_installinit
    dh_installmenu
    dh_installmime
    dh_installmodules
    dh_installlogcheck
    dh_installlogrotate
    dh_installpam
    dh_installppp
    dh_installudev
    dh_installwm
    dh_installxfonts
    dh_bugfiles
    dh_lintian
    dh_gconf
    dh_icons
    dh_perl
    dh_pysupport
    dh_usrlocal
    dh_link
    jh_installlibs
    jh_classpath
    jh_manifest
    jh_exec
    jh_depends
make: *** [binary] Error 1
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it open. Regards